# Impressão de boleto na página de sucesso com Magento

Tags: magento, boleto

Uso os módulos: `onestepcheckout` + `Inovarti_BoletoBancario_Magento_2016-master`.
Eles tem tudo, menos o botão para a impressão de boleto na página de sucesso.

Já tentei algumas maneiras mas o máximo que consegui foi um botão para a página de pedido.